# GAN PyTorch: Same Images Generating throughout batches

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

So the problem can be seen by looking at the image below

[Image generated per epoch screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s8zg.png)
The images per batch are same but not identical like only 5% pizels differ a bit

The latent size of random noise used sent to the generator of saving images at the end of each epoch is torch.randn(Batch_size,Latent_size,1,1)

But It seems as if the Generative model is forcing itself irespective of the random noise input being different per image,
and on contrary the random noise is constant throughout diff epochs but the image generation keeps changing.

Code:

```
#Data Preparation
import torchvision.transforms as tt
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

#mean = (0.6528, 0.4833, 0.4052)
#deviation = (0.2362, 0.2079, 0.1988)

ROOT = "./data/Gender/train"
BATCH_SIZE = 120
LATENT_SIZE = 100

train_ds = ImageFolder(ROOT, tt.Compose([tt.RandomHorizontalFlip(),tt.Resize(64),tt.ToTensor(),tt.Normalize((0.6528, 0.4833, 0.4052),(0.2362, 0.2079, 0.1988))]))
train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=1, num_workers=2, pin_memory=1)
```

```
#Generator

G = nn.Sequential(
    nn.ConvTranspose2d(LATENT_SIZE,800,kernel_size=4,stride=2,padding=1,bias=False),#1000 2 2 
    nn.BatchNorm2d(800),
    nn.ReLU(),

    nn.ConvTranspose2d(800,400,kernel_size=4,stride=2,padding=1,bias=False),#600 4 4
    nn.BatchNorm2d(400),
    nn.ReLU(),
    
    nn.ConvTranspose2d(400,200,kernel_size=4,stride=2,padding=1,bias=False),#300 8 8
    nn.BatchNorm2d(200),
    nn.ReLU(),
    
    nn.ConvTranspose2d(200,100,kernel_size=4,stride=2,padding=1,bias=False),#150 16
    nn.BatchNorm2d(100),
    nn.ReLU(),
    
    nn.ConvTranspose2d(100,50,kernel_size=4,stride=2,padding=1,bias=False),#50 32
    nn.BatchNorm2d(50),
    nn.ReLU(),
    
    nn.ConvTranspose2d(50,3,kernel_size=4,stride=2,padding=1,bias=False),#3 64
    nn.Tanh()
)

G = G.to(device)
```

```
#Generator Traing Function

def g_fit():
    g_opt.zero_grad()
    
    rand_g = torch.randn(BATCH_SIZE, LATENT_SIZE,1,1,dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
    fake_images = G(rand_g)
    g_loss = loss_fn(D(fake_images), real_labels)
    

    g_loss.backward()
    
    g_opt.step()
    
    return g_loss
```

```
#Saving Images

from torchvision.utils import save_image
from PIL import Image

gen = torch.randn(24,LATENT_SIZE,1,1).to(device)

def save_fake_images(epoch):

    with torch.no_grad():
        fake_images = G(gen)

        name = "./drive/MyDrive/gans_data/fake_n_images_"+str(epoch)+".png"
        
        #Denorming Images
        for i in range(len(fake_images)):
            fake_images[i][0]=(fake_images[i][0]*0.2362) +0.6528
            fake_images[i][1]=(fake_images[i][1]*0.2079) +0.4833
            fake_images[i][2]=(fake_images[i][2]*0.1988) +0.4052

        save_image(fake_images, name, nrow=6)

#this function is being used at the end of every training loop to save a small batch of images
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in the training of GANs, called *mode collapse*. Please have a look at some info on how to solve this:

https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/gan/problems#mode-collapse
https://machinelearningmastery.com/practical-guide-to-gan-failure-modes/

On personal experience, I've found training GANs to be pretty fickle, and sometimes something will work once and then not work the next training run, or minor changes in some parameters will have a large effect on the performance of the generator. Keep trying new things and see how they go.

Comment: I did read the google one and understood the reason it happens.
its just that the Discrimainator gets stuck in the local minima and the generator exploits the fact by only generation best images for that minima.
So i increased the batch size from 120 to 500 in hapes that the local minima is cloas to the global and the Discriminator has a variety of input, it did help a bit but the result is still in patches half the inputs are one type and other half of other type.
GANs are fickle indeed

Comment: Are you using a WGAN? Some other tips include reducing the size of your networks, not using batch norm, running training of the fake/real images separately for the disc., reducing the learning rate etc. A good list can be found here: https://towardsdatascience.com/10-lessons-i-learned-training-generative-adversarial-networks-gans-for-a-year-c9071159628